# Problems when creating Game Board: prints too many lists

Tags: python-3.x, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to create a game board using lists, but when I'm printing the board it prints way too many lists.

```
from random import randint
import pprint

class Gameboard:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self._rows = rows
        self._columns = columns
        self._board = []
        for i in range(rows):
            row = [0] * columns
            self._board.append(row)

    def drawBoard(self):
        for i in range(self._rows):
            for j in range(self._columns):
                pprint.pprint(self._board)
```

Main program:

```
from gameboard import Gameboard
import pprint

def main():
    myObject = Gameboard(7, 7)
    myObject.drawBoard()
main()
```

My goal is to create a board that consists of (in this case) 7 lists with 7 elements within a list.
When I run the program now, it prints about 7*49 lists or something. What must I change to only print out one list with 7 lists within?

Comment: is this python2 or 3?

Comment: Your drawBoard is iterating over `_rows * _columns` and printing `_rows` number of rows (of columns)

Comment: @BurnsBA It is python 3

Comment: I would suggest changing the tags to `python` and `python-3.x` to get helpful replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an inline for loop to generate a list of `"[]"` strings and then iterate that print function however many times you needed, like the below:

```
import pprint

for i in range(7):
    pprint.pprint(["[]" for j in range(7)])
```

---

By using `.join()` on the list you could also concatenate every element in the list into one long string, which looks arguably better.

```
import pprint

for i in range(7):
    pprint.pprint(' '.join(["[]" for j in range(7)]))
```

Comment: @danny_blue Does this fix the problem you were having or do you still need it to be 1 list with 7 lists inside?

Comment: I think this will be approved, I had to leave for the night but I'll countinue to work with the assignment and check it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
def drawBoard(self):
    print(*self._board, sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```